# CSS Display span and button elements on same line in container div with text-align: center

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML like so:

```
    <div class="request" style="text-align: center">
        <span>{{ request.username }} wants to be your friend!</span>
        <form action="/accept_friend" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ request.user_a }}" name="sender_id">
            <button type="submit">Accept</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I want to display the button to the right of the span text on the same line.  Currently the button is below the span.

If I remove `style="text-align: center"` from the container div and add `style="float: left"` to the span, it displays correctly but not centered in the page like I also want.  I have played around with the display attribute a bit but haven't found the proper solution through trial and error.  Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `display: inline;` or `inline-block` for the `form` (otherwise it will be a block and 100% wide by default):

```css
form {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="request" style="text-align: center">
        <span>{{ request.username }} wants to be your friend!</span>
        <form action="/accept_friend" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ request.user_a }}" name="sender_id">
            <button type="submit">Accept</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, I had tried using display: inline on both the span and button, but not the form itself.  Thanks.  Will mark as answer ASAP